# Unable to host my website

Tags: router, website, windows-server-2016, web-hosting

my public IP is 183.x.y.z and my web serve IP is 198.168.0.104. when i tried to host my website it is directed to router page. i have posted a screenshot, can anyone help me?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is this from inside or outside your network. Also have you tried forwarding an alternate port to test? Lots of routers assuming you want to use port 80 for management only - you can adjust settings but its router dependant

Comment: You generally cannot test port forwarding from inside the network. It can work, but mostly it does not.

Comment: this is from outside the network